# jquery get window position + scroll - but if not scroll not show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

Hi have few photos show up on scroll. 
I use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll( function(){
        $('.fade').each( function(i){
            var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + ( $(this).outerHeight() / 2 );
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
            if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){
                $(this).addClass('showme');
            }
            if( bottom_of_window < bottom_of_object ){
                $(this).removeClass('showme');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This work so well, but when I open the page if the **windows is to high the photos doesn't show up** and let a with space very ugly. It (I think) is Because the add class work only on the window scroll.

How can I solve this problem? I need when the pictures show up in relation at the windows position and not only at the scroll?

Thank you!

Comment: What you need is called lazy loading. Why don't you use a plugin for this?

Comment: Would be better if you'll share your tries in snippet/fiddlr

Comment: If  "It (I think) is Because the add class work only on the window scroll." is true, just add your class when document is ready. You've already implemented such functionality, just find element which you'd like to add class, and do your job. instead `$(this).addClass('showme');` use `$(your_selector).addClass('showme');` before `$(window).scroll()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append `scroll` triggering to the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll( function(){
        $('.fade').each( function(i){
            var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + ( $(this).outerHeight() / 2 );
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
            if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){
                $(this).addClass('showme');
            }
            if( bottom_of_window < bottom_of_object ){
                $(this).removeClass('showme');
            }
        });
    });

    $(window).scroll();
});
```

`$(window).scroll()` triggers `scroll` event on `window` - [docs](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/).

Comment: Thank so much! in this way work well also on tablet!! And thank you the docs!